# Cannot clone a GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, vscode-remote

> D:\rsetau-management λ git config --global --unset http.proxy
>
> D:\rsetau-management λ git clone
> https://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git Cloning
> into 'restaurant-management-system'... fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git/':
> Unsupported proxy syntax in 'aproxy:airport': Port number was not a
> decimal number between 0 and 65535

Comment: Have you tried `git config --unset http.proxy` ... remove the `--global`?

Comment: The error info is very clear. Your proxy port is not a valid number.

Comment: How can I now the port number cause I haev alraedy use  a commande anad I set the port number 8080 just to test but it still giving an error as you see

I run this commande with my password and username and localhost and 8080 as a port number :
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport

Comment: Does the error message contain the flat string `aproxy:airport` ? or `localhost:8080` ?

Answer (score 0):

As a first attempt to figure out what's going wrong, you could use `git config -l` to print all global and local configuration to make sure there are no more proxy settings active (perhaps locally, since you passed the `--global` on the `unset`). (if you plan to put the output here please keep in mind to redact personal or confidential values)

Answer (score 0):

maybe stupid advice, but still

1. Check Global Git Config:

*Ensure that there are no proxy settings in your global Git configuration.*

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy

git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

2. Check Local Git Config:

*If you are inside a Git repository, make sure to check the local configuration as well.*

```
git config --unset http.proxy

git config --unset https.proxy
```

3. Clone Without Proxy:

Try to clone the repository without using any proxy settings.

```
git clone https://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git
```

Comment: I tried all this commande but still the same probleme :

Output : 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git/': Unsupported proxy syntax in 'aproxy:airport': Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535

Comment: Note that I haev alraedy use a commande and I set the port number 8080 just to test but it still giving an error as you see I run this commande with my password and username and localhost and 8080 as a port number : set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:

Comment: how about -> "Environment Variables"

Check if there are any environment variables (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY) set that might be affecting Git.

Comment: one more case)

for this file setup some instructions
`~/.gitconfig:`

[http]
    proxy = http://your.proxy.server:your_proxy_port
[https]
    proxy = http://your.proxy.server:your_proxy_port

Comment: How can I get proxyserver and proxy port